# Picker View for button action getting crashed

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, ibaction

I have a picker view,when the row component of a picker view is selected,it navigates to a view,there I have a button changeGroup.On clicking the button the picker view must appear,but it is not happening! Its crashing

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
groupArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Family",@"Friends",@"Office",@"Acquaintances", nil]autorelease];
    agrpPicker.hidden  = YES;
}

#pragma mark-
#pragma mark PickerView Datasource

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    int number = 0;

    if (agrpPicker.hidden == NO) 
    {
        number = 1;
    }

    return number;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    int count = 0;
    if (agrpPicker.hidden == NO) 
    {
        count = [self.groupArr count];
    }
    return count;
}

#pragma mark-
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc]init]autorelease];

    if (agrpPicker.hidden == NO) 
    {
        str = [self.groupArr objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    return str;
}
```

This is the action for the button for the picker view to appear:

```
-(IBAction)groupButtonSelceted:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    CGAffineTransform transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);
    agrpPicker.transform = transfrom;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    agrpPicker.hidden = [agrpPicker isHidden] ? NO : YES;
    [self.view addSubview:agrpPicker];
}
```

connected that picker view to the picker view present in IB.

Here is the screen shot of where it got crashed

[image]

and in the console,the message appears as in snap shot below:

[image]

Can any expert point me out at where I went wrong....

Please help me out with your valuable suggestions,thanks in advance :)

Sorry guys,I found out what was the mistake,I haven't retained the array once it is autoreleased,instead of:

groupArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Family",@"Friends",@"Office",@"Acquaintances", nil]autorelease];

it is self.groupArr = ....;

Thanks for all who viewed and for those who contributed in fixing the issue :)

Comment: can you put crash logs also here?

Comment: @rishi yeah Mr.Rishi,I have placed a snap shot for clear understanding,please see the edited answer,thanks in advance :)

Comment: As per the screen shot it seems like memory issue, reference to an unallocated object. Is there anything present on console logs as well?

Comment: Nothing in console Mr.Rishi except (gdb)

Comment: Can you share code of picker view that you had in your application, there is something wrong in the code itself.

Comment: @rishi Yeah Mr.Rishi I have posted the code,please check the edited question,thanks for the patience and concern :)

Comment: @rishi I found out the mistake I did rishi,please see the last 2 lines of edited post,thanks once again for the concern,bye TC :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your groupArr array is loosing its contant due to autorelease. so change this

groupArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Family",@"Friends",@"Office",@"Acquaintances", nil];

[groupArr retain];

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but I have fixed it anyway using

self.groupArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Family",@"Friends",@"Office",@"Acquaintances", nil];

Comment: reload picker view. Use this code [agrpPicker reloadAllComponents]; on button pressed

Answer (score 0):

Add UIPickerViewDelegate in .h file.

And in .m file, add the PickerView delegate and datasource methods.
Datasource:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

Delegate:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

For more details, refer to [UIPickerView class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate) from Apple.

Comment: Please see the edited question(post),please provide me with a solution,thanks for the answer anyway :)